# Read in txt file as numpy array per block

Tags: python, numpy, readfile

I would like to print an array per block of data loaded from a txt file.

My data looks like this, blocks are separated with a white/blank line in between:

```
2 3 4
1 9 3
3 7 2

2 3 2
0 9 8

2 8 2
1 1 1
8 2 0
3 8 2
```

I would like to print the blocks in a for loop.

Comment: This isn't a place to ask people to write code for you from nothing. You should follow a beginner tutorial, then try to write a program to do this yourself first. *Then* we can help with specific questions if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = []

with open('notepad.txt','r') as file:    
    for line in file:
        if line != '\n':
            array.append(line.strip().split(' '))
        else: 
            print(array)
            array = []      
print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension.

```
with open('file.txt','r') as file:
   print([' '.join(t).split(' ') for t in [r.split('\n') for r in [e for e in file.read().split('\n\n')]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

> read in txt file as **numpy** array per **block**

With `numpy.core.records.fromrecords` routine:

```
import numpy as np

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = []
    for l in f:
        if l.strip():
            data.append(l.split())
        else:
            print(np.array(np.core.records.fromrecords(data).tolist(), dtype=np.int), '\n')
            data.clear()
    if data: print(np.array(np.core.records.fromrecords(data).tolist(), dtype=np.int))
```

The output:

```
[[2 3 4]
 [1 9 3]
 [3 7 2]] 

[[2 3 2]
 [0 9 8]] 

[[2 8 2]
 [1 1 1]
 [8 2 0]
 [3 8 2]]
```